# How can i go to startup page after successful registration from html registration page in blazorCoreHosted Applicatiom

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, blazor

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="signupbox" style="margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Sign Up</div>
                <div style="float:right; font-size: 85%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a id="signinlink" href="LoginPage.html" onclick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show()">Sign In</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fulltname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onchange="Error()" id="name" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="email" onchange="Error()" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="password" onchange="Error()" id="pass" class="form-control" name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password2" class="col-md-3 control-label">Repeat</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="password" onchange="Error()" id="repass" class="form-control" name="passwd2" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mobile" class="col-md-3 control-label">Mobile</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onchange="Error()" id="mobile" class="form-control" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="checkbox" data-pg-collapsed>
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value=""> I accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions of Service</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            <button id="btn-signup" onclick="Postdata()" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>   Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

I use Api Controller for Updating to my database.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'api/Register/Insertuser',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (d) {
                    alert("Success");
                   // window.open("LoginPage.html","_self");
                   window.open("index.html","_self");
                    Clear();

                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            })
```

I want , When registration is success then start up page will will run in web assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can navigate to the startup page using **Window.location**
- Start learning Blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0
- Don't use jQuery to make Http requests. Actually, don't use jQuery in your Blazor Apps at all. Use the HttpClient Service provided by the Blazor framework to make Http requests.
- Use the IUriHelper to navigate internally ( and externally if required)
- Use Blazor's form and input Components, as for instance, EditForm and InputText, to receive input data from users.
- Use the Authentication and Authorization built-in systems of Blazor to authenticate and authorize users of your application. They are excellently cooked and can save you a great deal of time, bugs, and low level of security vulnerabilities.
- Again, start learning Blazor: Start from the beginning

More question ???